# Setting width ratio in relative layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

Im pretty new to Android Layouts.

Im trying to set Age:EditText:Year in ratio 1:3:1 and same size on Height.

Should I use TableLayout? If yes how can i prevent TableRow1 from changing width etc when I do some stuff in other rows?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                          >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Age"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtYears"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Years"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtYears"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtAge"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your age"
        android:inputType="text|number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:maxLines="1" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enterHeight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_text"
        android:text="Height"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtHeight"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinHeight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtHeight"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your height"
        android:inputType="text|number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:maxLines="1" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you draw how you want to have your layout ?

Comment: is this what you want or this is what you have so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want. see image below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Years"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Height"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error ? maybe you forgot to include the first line ?
See the edit and copy the code again. I have the screen shot, so it works with me.

Comment: I think now, its fine. Check the answer again. I forgot to copy the last line.

Comment: Had to restart eclipse. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use linear layout.you can set `android:weightSum="10"` properties.

Its total layout. now you have to set for chilled object using `android:layout_weight="2"`.

So that will control your object in layout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="Age" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="6" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="Years" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have something like this.. Pseudo code untested..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/firstLinearLayout"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

<TextView

        android:weight = "2"
        />

 <TextView

        android:weight = "6"
        />

    <EditText

        android:weight = "2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/loginButtonLayout"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">
</LinearLayout>
```